# How to make all or most variable values visible when debugging in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

After compiling some variables are not visible when cursor move over them under debug mode. My guess is the compiler optimized those variables. However, for the sake of easier debug, I would like to see all or most of the variables. How could I set VS options to do so?